# The text of my depoiments slider component it's overflowing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, arrays, overflow

I created a map() of some depoiments and I'm trying to create a slider of depoiments using transform: translateX. But when I use "white-space: nowrap" the text overflows and any other css command break the text, I tried text-overflow, overflow-wrap, breakword, and others. Can anyone help me?

JSX:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, Button, Heading, Image, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { GrFormNext, GrFormPrevious } from "react-icons/gr";
import depoimentos from "./data";
import "./depoiments.css";

export const Depoiments = () => {
    const [currentDep, setCurrentDep] = useState(0);

    const prev = () => {
        const index = currentDep > 0 ? currentDep - 1 : depoimentos.length - 1;
        setCurrentDep(index);
    };

    const next = () => {
        const index = currentDep < depoimentos.length - 1 ? currentDep + 1 : 0;
        setCurrentDep(index);
    };

    return (
        <>
<Box className="titleContainer">
                <Box className="dpTitle">
                    <Heading as="h3" size="lg" id="depoiments">
                        Depoimentos
                    </Heading>
                    <Box>
                        <Button className="dpButton">
                            <GrFormPrevious onClick={prev} />
                        </Button>
                        <Button className="dpButton">
                            <GrFormNext onClick={next} />
                        </Button>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </Box>
            <Box className="dpContainer">
                <Box
                    className="dpBoxes"
                    style={{ transform: `translateX(${-currentDep * 100}%)` }}
                >
                    {depoimentos.map((depoiments) => {
                        const { name, text, img } = depoiments;

                        return (
                            <Box className="depoiments">
                                <Text>{text}</Text>
                                <Image src={img} alt="Estudante da Formei" />
                                <Heading as="h4" size="md">
                                    {name}
                                </Heading>
                            </Box>
                        );
                    })}
                </Box>
            </Box>
```

CSS:

```
    .titleContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    width: 100vw;
   }

.dpContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
   }

.dpBoxes {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
  }

.dpTitle {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;

    width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--darkBlue);
  }

.dpButton {
    background-color: var(--orange);
    margin: 2px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

.depoiments {
    border: 1px solid var(--darkBlue);
    border-radius: 16px;

    padding: 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;

    width: 100vw;

    display: inline-block;
  }

.depoiments h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
  }

.depoiments p {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }

.depoiments img {
    width: 20%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
  }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .dpBoxes {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        max-width: 90%;
    }

    .depoiments h4 {
        font-size: 32px;
    }

    .depoiments p {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 26px;
    }
}
```

Data:

Answer (score 0):

When using transform: translateX for creating a slider effect, it can be challenging to handle the text wrapping correctly within the sliding container. To achieve the slider effect without text overflowing, you can use the following approach:

Wrap each depoiment inside a separate container (e.g., a div).
Set the display: flex property on the container holding all depoiment containers (`.dpBoxes`). Add `flex-shrink: 0` to each depoiment container to prevent it from shrinking when the parent container's width reduces.
Set a fixed width for each depoiment container so that they don't collapse when the text wraps. Use overflow: hidden on the `.dpBoxes` container to hide the overflowing depoiments. Here's the updated CSS code:

```
.dpBoxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.depoiments {
    border: 1px solid var(--darkBlue);
    border-radius: 16px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

By using this approach, you'll maintain the sliding effect while ensuring that the text inside each depoiment container wraps correctly without overflowing. The `flex-shrink: 0` property prevents the depoiments from resizing and collapsing, and `overflow: hidden` hides any content that overflows the `.dpBoxes` container.

Please make these changes in your CSS, and it should resolve the issue with text overflowing in the slider of depoiments.